# openGLでモデルを描画する方法。

Tags: c++, opengl

提示コードはモデルデータの.objファイルですが頂点数が足りないため正常に立方体が描画出来ません。**そもそもoepnglでどう作成されたモデルをインポートするべきなのでしょうか？**ブレンダーで作成しましたが.objファイルの構造がおかしいためちょっとやり方が違うものと推測出来ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
  # Blender v2.91.0 OBJ File: ''
    # www.blender.org
    mtllib Cube.mtl
    o Cube
    v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
    v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
    v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
    v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
    v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
    v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
    v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
    v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
    vt 0.625000 0.500000
    vt 0.875000 0.500000
    vt 0.875000 0.750000
    vt 0.625000 0.750000
    vt 0.375000 0.750000
    vt 0.625000 1.000000
    vt 0.375000 1.000000
    vt 0.375000 0.000000
    vt 0.625000 0.000000
    vt 0.625000 0.250000
    vt 0.375000 0.250000
    vt 0.125000 0.500000
    vt 0.375000 0.500000
    vt 0.125000 0.750000
    vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
    vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
    vn -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
    vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
    vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
    vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
    usemtl Material
    s off
    f 1/1/1 5/2/1 7/3/1 3/4/1
    f 4/5/2 3/4/2 7/6/2 8/7/2
    f 8/8/3 7/9/3 5/10/3 6/11/3
    f 6/12/4 2/13/4 4/5/4 8/14/4
    f 2/13/5 1/1/5 3/4/5 4/5/5
    f 6/11/6 5/10/6 1/1/6 2/13/6
```

Comment: OpenGLか不明ですが、データ確認はこれで出来るのでは？ [Hira 3D Viewer](https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/winnt/art/se379971.html) あとはソースとかその辺はこれらが参考になるかも。[benikabocha/saba](https://github.com/benikabocha/saba), [clfm/model-viewer](https://github.com/RippeR37/OpenGL-OBJ-Viewer), [RippeR37/OpenGL-OBJ-Viewer](https://github.com/RippeR37/OpenGL-OBJ-Viewer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenGLでobjファイルの3Dデータを表示してみる](https://drumath.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/06/183623)

このサイトはOpenGLでの描画の参考になると思います。

あとWikipediaの.objファイルの記事も [Wavefront .objファイル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB)

要はobjファイルは元のモデルの頂点座標やテクスチャ座標などをそれぞれ表すということです。これをOpenGLで描画するにはある程度自分でOpenGLのコードを書く必要があるかなと思います。OpenGLで描画するためのライブラリやツールもあるかもしれませんが、おそらく目的がOpenGLの勉強ではないかと考えたのでここでは書きません。

さて、[OpenGLでobjファイルの3Dデータを表示してみる](https://drumath.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/06/183623)のサイトでやっていることの概要を書くと

- objファイルを、標準入力で読み込みやすいようにRubyで整形する
- 整形したファイルをfreeglutで書いたプログラム(自作のobjファイルビューワ)に読み込ませて実行

  - freeglutはOpenGLの実装の一つで、教育用その他でよく使われています
- objファイルビューワ内部ではobjファイルで指定された座標でメッシュを描画

といった流れです、ある程度コピペで真似できるのではないでしょうか